# FastCGI PHP-FPM autoload.php permission

Tags: permissions, php, nginx, centos-7, composer

I installed LEMP both with RH and REMI, and I have the problem as in PHP-FPM has no permission to require autoload.php and `php_info();` works fine. I can require any other file but this. I also tried to set permissions to 0777 and group owners was set to `nginx:nginx`, but does not work; I don't know why.

This is the error I got from nginx/error.log:

```
[error] 8450#0: *56 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: require(/usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php on line 22 
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php on line 22"
```

The strange thing is if change the content of autoload.php to `<?php php_info(); ?>` it works.

I followed [How to Install Nginx, MySQL, PHP v7 (LEMP) stack on CentOS 7](https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-install-lemp-centos7) and also [How to Install and Configure a LEMP Stack using Software Collections on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-lemp-stack-software-collections-centos-7) .